# Not able to hardcode file directory for CSV parsing using Papa Parse

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I am trying to parse a .csv file that will be in an already known local directory using Papa Parse in Javascript. If I have a mechanism to ask the user to browse for the file, it works like a charm. But I can't figure out how to get it to automatically access the file at a given location. I feel like I am missing something simple, but I'm not sure what. My code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>testing papa parse</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/PapaParse-4.0.7/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var data;
    // var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var file = "\\files\\telemetryData.csv";

      Papa.parse(file, {
      //makes sure the first line is interpreted as a header, not data
      header: true,

      //allows stuff to be typed as their respective primitive types instead of only strings. turned off in this case
      dynamicTyping: false,

      //allows you to define the delimiter if not a default comma
      delimiter: ",",

      //allows you to define a comment line, which would be skipped by the parser
      comments: "//",

      //turns on fastmode, quicker but assumes no quoted fields is present
      fastmode: true,

      download: true,

      step: function(results){
        console.log(results.data);
      }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

csv data:

```
TEAM_ID,MISSION_TIME,ALT_SENSOR,OUTSIDE_TEMP,INSIDE_TEMP,VOLTAGE,FSW_STATE
ubArtemis,0,36,20,20,9,1
ubArtemis,1,45,18,20,9,1
ubArtemis,2,50,16,20,9,1
ubArtemis,3,65,14,19,9,1
ubArtemis,4,79,12,17,8,2
//hello this is a comment
ubArtemis,5,100,10,16,8,3
ubArtemis,6,120,8,15,8,4
ubArtemis,7,145,6,14,8,5
ubArtemis,8,160,4,12,7,6
ubArtemis,9,200,2,10,6,7
```

Comment: You can't do this, for good reason. It would be very bad indeed if a script on any site could arbitrarily access any file on any visitor's computer.

Comment: I see. Would there be a workaround for this?

Comment: Yeah, the user has to select it from a `<input type="file">` element or you have to download it by passing a URL.

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery to "get" the file contents and use papaparse to parse the csv string:

```
//parse the data file
    var csvfile = "data/data.csv";

    $.get(csvfile, function (data) {
        var csvdata = Papa.parse(data);
        console.log(csvdata);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to read the data from file before you use it for parsing.the below code is working for me

```
    Papa.parse(fs.createReadStream(file), {
        delimiter: ",",
        header: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
            done();
        }
    });
```